# How to get store API response of type array in typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, get

The api returns a response like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "code": "string",
    "name": "string",
  }
]
```

So for example it will be

```
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "code": "CODE1",
    "name": "name1",
  },
  {
    "id": "cdf",
    "code": "CODE2",
    "name": "name2",
  }
]
```

How do I store it in a typescript interface? I initially tried it like this

```
export interface promotionCodes {
  id: string,
  code: string,
  name: string,
}

export interface getPromotionsResponse {
  data: promotionCodes[]
}
```

and I call it as:

```
return await this.get<getPromotionsResponse>(
  `myurl`,
);
```

But I don't think this will work since I don't have anything named 'data' being returned in my call but I'm not sure how else to store it? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `type` that is an array of the other type:

```
export type getPromotionsResponse = promotionCodes[];
```

If you *have to* create an `interface` and not a `type`, you'll need to do it like this:

```
export interface getPromotionsResponse {
    [index: number]: promotionCodes;
}
```

Or better yet, as [Mack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8580499/mack) suggested in the comments, you can also extend the array interface, so your new type would have all the functionalities of an array.

```
export interface getPromotionsResponse extends Array<promotionCodes> {}
```

Comment: One better than this interface is `export interface getPromotionsResponse extends Array<promotionCodes> {}`. Array is just an interface too :)

Comment: oh yeah, very good point. i'll update the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use typescript generics for this purpose
Here is the link to the docs:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html